# Assign named placeholder to a variable (as a string)

Tags: output-formatting

If I want to assign a regular placeholder as a string, it's very easy:
(anything the user types in will automatically be given quotes around it, so when they evaluate the cell str is a string)

```
 str = "\[Placeholder]"
```

I just can't get quotes around a named placeholder (not while assigning to a variable, at least):

```
 str2 = {"\"", Placeholder[ProjectName], "\""}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I've got it, apologies for the self-answered post.  It was treating the "=" as a string that caught me off guard.    

     MakeBoxes[string ], RowBox[{"=",  "\"", 
      ToBoxes@Placeholder[enter here], "\""}]

Comment: Please answer your own question if you found the answer :)

Comment: I can't yet, too few rep :(
If you'd like, take it and answer in my stead!

Comment: How about now? 6 rep should be enough.. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. "

Comment: @user15921 - maybe now?

Comment: Aww you guys are the best! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It was treating the "=" as a string that caught me off guard.

```
NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
  Cell[BoxData[
   RowBox[{MakeBoxes[string], 
     RowBox[{"=", "\"", ToBoxes@Placeholder[enter here], "\""}]
   }] 
  ]]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Even if your code helped you to answer your own question, it doesn't seem to work for me. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add full context.
In my own code this is written to a new notebook, where the user fills in the placeholder and evaluates to save their input as the variable string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
x = "";
InputField[Dynamic@x, String, ContinuousAction -> True]
Dynamic@InputForm@x
```

Comment: Appending `FieldHint -> "Enter Project Name", FieldHintStyle -> Red` would make your answer, which is nice, nicer :)

Comment: This is pretty spiffy, thanks! I like the aesthetics of the InputFields, but I think placeholders are better for 'savability';  if you fill them out and save the nb the code stays, but with input forms if you close the kernel, you loose what you've typed in.

Comment: @user15921 well, sure context matters here :)